# nginx redirect fails if original request is non-existent

Tags: php, nginx, redirect

**Problem Statement:**  nginx appears not to redirect when the original request is a non-existent location. All other redirects appear to work just fine. It is also possible that php is not executing the script on the redirected page. nginx conf is provided below.

**Questions:**  What am I missing and what do I need to do to make this work? Is it possible that nginx does not support redirection from a non-existent page?

**Some context may be helpful:** Here is a typical request that is being redirected:

```
73.234.24.22 - - [30/May/2022:16:15:05 +0000] "GET /postevent3.asp?dta=05%2f30%2f22%2016%3a15%3a22%20507%20%2b149642656%20%2d254084882%20%2d0001787%20682829361 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "-"
```

Please note that there is no page display intended for this request; the request is dumped into a buffer, processed and written to a database. Please see the end of this post for an extract from the nginx debug log.

It is not practical to change the URL because there are dozens of units scattered about the world. Most units cannot be updated remotely.

The original site that is not in use now, utilized apache. The current site uses nginx. I am not very conversant with web servers, so I have probably missed something obvious. All thoughts will be appreciated.

I have also tried the following in the port 80 server block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /data/submit_legacy.php?$query_string;
}
```

**nginx conf file-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/example.org;
    server_name example.org www.example.org ;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    expires    -1;
    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/www/example.org/data/http-org-submit.log debug;

#=# ========================================================================= #=#       
#=# Intercept request for postevent3.asp and send it data/submit_legacy.php,  #=# 
#=# be sure to change to return 301 when testing is complete                  #=#       
#=# ========================================================================= #=#       

    location = /postevent3.asp {
        return 302 https://example.org/data/submit_legacy.php?$query_string; 
    }       

    location / {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    root /var/www/example.org;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    expires    -1;
    
    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/www/example.org/data/https-org-submit.log debug;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypta/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;  includeSubDomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    
    client_max_body_size 100M;  
}
```

**Extract from nginx debug file:---------------------------------------------------------------**

```
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055BC271BE300, pos 000055BC271BE300, size: 390 file: 0, size: 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:390
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http output filter "/postevent3.asp?dta=05%2f30%2f22%2017%3a35%3a32%20564%20%2b188886495%20%2b025481359%20%2b0005990%20570742577"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http copy filter: "/postevent3.asp?dta=05%2f30%2f22%2017%3a35%3a32%20564%20%2b188886495%20%2b025481359%20%2b0005990%20570742577"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 image filter
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 xslt filter body
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http postpone filter "/postevent3.asp?dta=05%2f30%2f22%2017%3a35%3a32%20564%20%2b188886495%20%2b025481359%20%2b0005990%20570742577" 000055BC271BE5D0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055BC271BE300, pos 000055BC271BE300, size: 390 file: 0, size: 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055BC260A7AC0, size: 92 file: 0, size: 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055BC260A7E20, size: 62 file: 0, size: 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:544
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http write filter limit 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 writev: 544 of 544
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/postevent3.asp?dta=05%2f30%2f22%2017%3a35%3a32%20564%20%2b188886495%20%2b025481359%20%2b0005990%20570742577"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/postevent3.asp?dta=05%2f30%2f22%2017%3a35%3a32%20564%20%2b188886495%20%2b025481359%20%2b0005990%20570742577" a:1, c:1
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 set http keepalive handler
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http close request
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http log handler
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 free: 000055BC271E7D10, unused: 10
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 free: 000055BC271BDE40, unused: 1875
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 free: 000055BC2719E1B0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 tcp_nodelay
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 reusable connection: 1
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 event timer add: 32: 65000:84579871
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 http keepalive handler
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 malloc: 000055BC2719E1B0:1024
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 recv: eof:1, avail:-1
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 recv: fd:32 0 of 1024
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [info] 37669#37669: *1 client 93.181.63.177 closed keepalive connection
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 close http connection: 32
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 event timer del: 32: 84579871
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 reusable connection: 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 free: 000055BC2719E1B0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *1 free: 000055BC271E7B00, unused: 136
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http header: "Host: www.example.org"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http header done
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 event timer del: 32: 84575067
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 generic phase: 0
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 rewrite phase: 1
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 test location: "/"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 test location: "postevent3.asp"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 using configuration "=/postevent3.asp"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 rewrite phase: 3
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http set discard body
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http script copy: "https://example.org/data/submit_legacy.php?"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http script var: "dta=10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A24%2000096%20%2B204823178%20%2B089853375%20%2B0008360%20634488566%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A27%2000096%20%2B204823175%20%2B089853369%20%2B0008402%20392294994%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A31%2000096%20%2B204823170%20%2B089853326%20%2B0008462%20215533034%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A32%2000096%20%2B204823166%20%2B089853317%20%2B0008472%20020574633%20%0D%0A"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http finalize request: 302, "/postevent3.asp?dta=10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A24%2000096%20%2B204823178%20%2B089853375%20%2B0008360%20634488566%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A27%2000096%20%2B204823175%20%2B089853369%20%2B0008402%20392294994%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A31%2000096%20%2B204823170%20%2B089853326%20%2B0008462%20215533034%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A32%2000096%20%2B204823166%20%2B089853317%20%2B0008472%20020574633%20%0D%0A" a:1, c:1
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http special response: 302, "/postevent3.asp?dta=10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A24%2000096%20%2B204823178%20%2B089853375%20%2B0008360%20634488566%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A27%2000096%20%2B204823175%20%2B089853369%20%2B0008402%20392294994%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A31%2000096%20%2B204823170%20%2B089853326%20%2B0008462%20215533034%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A32%2000096%20%2B204823166%20%2B089853317%20%2B0008472%20020574633%20%0D%0A"
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 http set discard body
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 xslt filter header
2022/05/30 17:35:15 [debug] 37669#37669: *2 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 30 May 2022 17:35:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.org/data/submit_legacy.php?dta=10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A24%2000096%20%2B204823178%20%2B089853375%20%2B0008360%20634488566%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A27%2000096%20%2B204823175%20%2B089853369%20%2B0008402%20392294994%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A31%2000096%20%2B204823170%20%2B089853326%20%2B0008462%20215533034%20%0D%0A10%2F14%2F02%2017%3A35%3A32%2000096%20%2B204823166%20%2B089853317%20%2B0008472%20020574633%20%0D%0A
Expires: Mon, 30 May 2022 17:35:14 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: From the log you provided I can see the redirect was issued. I don't understand what does it mean "redirect fails" here. Maybe it isn't related, but using both `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` and `include fastcgi_params;` is somewhat redundant. The redirected request should be handled by `/var/www/example.org/data/submit_legacy.php` PHP script, is it an existing file?

Comment: Fails in this context means data never was received and entered into the database. Please note that there is no page display intended for this request; the request is dumped into a buffer, processed and written to a database. Please see the end of this post for an extract from the nginx debug log.

Comment: Debug log indicates that the request was accepted at the HTTP 80 port and the 302 temporary redirect to `https://example.org/data/submit_legacy.php?dta=...` **was** actually issued. What happened next is hidden in the dark. Whatever software initiated this request, are you sure it is able to interpret that `302 Moved Temporarily` HTTP redirect and issue a new HTTPS request? And once again, is `/var/www/example.org/data/submit_legacy.php` an actually existed PHP script intended to process this request?

Comment: Hello Ivan thanks for the help. I agree what happened next is hidden in the dark. I have tried placing php debug code in submit_legacy.php in the first line. It appears that the file is never accessed. submit_legacy.php is an actual file that interprets the request. You may be on to something regarding the redirecting from http to https; However, I have tried redirecting to http also to no avail. I am not sure about the software's ability to interpret a 302 request. Is that important? From my view, I have the data I need I just can't execute the php file.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand how nginx works. Are redirects sent back to the browser or issuing software that is then in charge of reissuing the request? If so this may be the root of the problem. The source of the request probably does not handle https or http2. Requests are issued as http/1.1.

Comment: Yes, and maybe this is not about the nginx itself, but about the HTTP protocol in common. Yes, it is the issuer who in charge of reissuing the request. Yes, to issue a request using HTTPS it should be able to handle the SSL cryptographic layer of that protocol. An HTTP/2 is another completely different thing, a binary protocol with the multiplexing abilities, much more complex from the developer point of view than the old good plaintext HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my guess that software initiated this request is unable to interpret the 302 HTTP redirection code and issue a new request is correct, your only way is to process the request inside the HTTP block itself. Instead of your current

```
location = /postevent3.asp {
    return 302 https://example.org/data/submit_legacy.php?$query_string; 
}
```

you can check this piece of configuration:

```
location = /postevent3.asp {
    rewrite ^ /data/submit_legacy.php break;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

If using this configuration your requests will start to appear in your database, that will definitely means my original guess is correct.

Comment: Ivan, I am indebted everything is working perfectly. I find it interesting that `rewrite ^ /data/submit_legacy.php break;` does not need to be appended with $query_string. In any event thank you. I now have my life back.

Comment: Yes, unlike `return 30x` or `try_files` directives where last argument should contain a query string in order to keep it, `rewrite` directive will keep the existing one, and if it is undesired, a question mark should be appended to the end of new URI, as described in the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).